# SQL Server Intergration Services 2005 - How do I get a directory listing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssis

In SQL Server Integration Services 2005, how do I read a directory so I can then process all of the files in that directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for a foreach loop like this example:

http://www.sqlis.com/post/Looping-over-files-with-the-Foreach-Loop.aspx